Could you provide a clear distinction between imperfect and perfect duties according to deontologists?
How are the two duties different from each other, while seemingly the same, just as Kant says with regards to the two duties.

Per Kant perfect duties are strict "must-not" rules that admit no exceptions (e.g., do not lie) since for example, lying cannot be universalized because it leads to a logical contradiction in the concept of truth-telling. Imperfect duties are flexible "should" guidelines aimed at moral growth (e.g., help others). Both types of duties serve to uphold the moral law, but they address different aspects of our moral lives—one ensuring respect for the moral order, the other fostering the broader goals of humanity...
